# Get config value in html using knockoutjs

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart, system-config, knockout

I am trying to get config value to html file. 
My aim is to check if the config value is enabled of it is show a button and if it’s continue normally with out button the button. 
I am not sure how to get the value to knockout js 
Can I pass it somehow in class or do I have to do anything else

Comment: Depends on how you are adding the component to the page. How are you adding the knockout component?

Comment: I am not sure how to add knockout to html

Answer (score 2):

### Create Helper For Accessing System Configuration Values

Here you would just create a helper that has some methods for fetching the system config values you want. `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper` already has access to Scope Config for getting values, but you could also just inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` into the block below and access that way.

### Create PHP Block for Exposing Configuration to Knockout Component

```
<?php

namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Block;

use YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Data as ModuleHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class YourComponent extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var SerializerInterface
     */
    protected $serializer;

    /**
     * @var ModuleHelper
     */
    protected $moduleHelper;

    /**
     * YourComponent constructor.
     *
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
     * @param ModuleHelper $moduleHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        ModuleHelper $moduleHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->moduleHelper = $moduleHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Get JSON configuration for your component.
     *
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        return $this->serializer->serialize([
            'is_enabled' => $this->moduleHelper->getIsEnabled(),
            'other_value' => $this->moduleHelper->getOtherValue()
        ]);
    }
}
```

### Pass Component Configuration via PHP Block

For brevity I'm just showing a component that's fully defined within the phtml template. The key part here is the `<?= $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>`, which is a method on the PHP Block that should output json encoded data, which would include your system config value.

> **Note:** Another way to pass the config into components is to define your component hierarchy via `jsLayout` using layout xml for this block, then target the component and inject the config by overriding the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::getJsLayout()` method that every block template has. That method will contain everything specified in the blocks `jsLayout`, giving you a chance to add/edit/modify it's contents before being used on the page.

```
<?php
/** @var YourCompany\YourModule\Block\YourComponentBlock $block */
?>

<div data-bind="scope: 'yourComponent'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "yourComponent": {
                        "component": "YourCompany_YourModule/js/view/your-component",
                        "template": "YourCompany_YourModule/your-component",
                        "config": <?= $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### Access the Configuration in the Knockout Component

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function(Component) {

    return Component.extend({
        /**
         * Initialize Component
         *
         * @param config
         */
        initialize: function(config) {
            this._super();
            this.is_enabled = config.is_enabled;
            this.other_value = config.other_value;
        }
    });
});
```